# replaced a dll in GAC_MSIL how do I rebuild that cache?

Tags: c#, powershell, dll, .net-assembly, dsc

Just a bit of a background im a sysadmin attempting to build a few C# library's for Powershell DSC. As a result i've replaced a few dll files with a more up to date version in the GAC_MSIL folder. This did fix the errors with my custom library however now the main code is yelling about

```
PSDesiredStateConfiguration\Node : The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
At D:\DSCResources\Configuration\ServerConfigs\ServerBaseline.ps1:36 char:2
```

one of the file locations are.

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OperationsManager\7.0.5000.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OperationsManager.dll
```

Can I rebuild this cache?

Comment: Just do not manually change it...

Comment: Yeah thats the problem I need fall back to the old version without shadow copies. Since its just a cache I assume you can just rebuild it? If that folder ever got deleted does it just come back?